# Autocomplete after dot in python

Tags: python, auto-complete-mode, jedi

I haven't used emacs before, but would like to learn how to use it properly for Python development.

From the past IDEs I have used I enjoyed the feature to obtain information on possible objects when I press <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>.
Also after each dot I would like to get a list of possible methods and functions.

Right now I am using a default auto-complete package but it only gives me the list after the first character after the dot which is a little impractical.

I've found jedi and installed it and added

```
;;Autocomplete
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional
```

in my `.emacs`. (Maybe someone can explain me why `t` is used after the `complete-on-dot`.)

But nothing relevant is happening. How should I solve that issue?

EDIT:
Got that warning:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: jedi:complete-on-dot

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Comment: I've followed this [link](https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) to setup my emacs python environment and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems Elpy already comes with jedi-support and if you use jedi in your configuration it overwrites the default conifg by Elpy.

I helped to reinstall the packages and remove the jedi-config